# Data(timestamp).toLocaleString always return current date

Tags: java, android

In this code

```
long timestamp=1332782463298;
Date d=new Date(timestamp);
date=d.toLocaleString();
```

`date` is always current date. Where is my mistake?

I've also tried SimpleDateFormat, but it still returns current date:

```
date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy").format(d);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That timestamp *is* for March 26th 2012 (17:21:03.298 UTC, to be precise). Try a suitably different timestamp (e.g. 1332482563298L) and you'll get a different date...

Note that you shouldn't really be using `toLocaleString` anyway - `SimpleDateFormat` is the way to go (or [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if possible). You might also want to consider which time zone you're interested in.

Comment: But this site converts it to Match 12th http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: @biovamp: It converts it to March 12th **44204** because it's assuming (well, stating) that the input value is in *seconds* since the Unix epoch, whereas the `Date` value is in *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but do you understand what `long timestamp=1332782463298;` is ? It's a UNIX time stamp in milliseconds since 1 January 1970, if you keep it same, `date` will contains same time all the time.

Comment: Yes, I'am understand. It's value returned from server. Looks like it's server-programmer's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar instead:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(1332782463298);
Date d = cal.getTime();
String current = SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy").format(cal.getTime()).toString();
```